# How to assign CSS properties to aside tag

Tags: css

I am trying to change the font family of an aside tag. I created the following section in my css file -

```
.instruction {
    color: brown;
    font: verdana;
}
```

and assigned aside, class = instruction. But it does not work. I have also tried  using aside as an element in CSS to assign the properties like
asign {property: value;}, but no effect.

But if I only use color property, then it works. So is there any issue with assigning font family and related properties to aside tag? I am using Chrome 28.

Comment: Suggest to use color codes instead of color constants. By the way, show your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font-family: verdana;` instead of `font: verdana` and when you are using `font` shorthand properties care of the following order:

```
1. font-style
2. font-variant
3. font-weight
4. font-size/line-height
5. font-family
```

And also you cannot apply just one value in shorthand method. For font, it should at least two values for eg. `font-siz` and `font-family`

[image]

[image source](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 1):

When using the `font` shorthand you must specify *at least* a `font-family` and a `font-size` - not just one or the other - the exception is when using system fonts - e.g. `font: menu;`

Also note that the `font-family` property must appear after `font-size`.

```
.instruction {
    color: brown;
    font: 1em verdana;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GRBRU/

Comment: [just mentioning] Could be a issue of overriding. if it so, then using `aside.instruction` instead of just `.instruction` is preferable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
{
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or:

```
{
  font: 13px bold Verdana;
}
```